# Using Retrieved Data from a Parameterized SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

If I'm using a parameterized query (ASP.NET with C#) in SQL, such as

```
var db = Database.Open("Database1");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pageinfo WHERE pageID = @pageID");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageID", 1);
```

And later on in the page, I want to do a foreach loop of whatever data was retrieved:

```
foreach(var row in ???)
```

What would I use (in place of the ???) to access the data I just retrieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on **how** you execute a query.

Usually it's done by [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example, in your case, you can:

```
.... 

 SqlDataReader reader = cmd .ExecuteReader();
 while (reader.Read())
 {
   ...
 }
```

But there are also other ways to rertieve the data, for example using [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zb0sdh0b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
For a complete example on how to do that can have a look on:

[Using ADO.NET for beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` iteration statement with [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) instead of `foreach`. Take a look this;

```
var db = Database.Open("Database1");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pageinfo WHERE pageID = @pageID");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageID", 1);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
}
```

`reader[0]` returns first row of first column and `reader[1]` returns first row of second column if your data has of course.